R data.table test whether value un column is in list column
Suppose I have the following data.table
dx <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3),tet=list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5),c(3)))

   x   tet
1: 1 1,2,3
2: 2   4,5
3: 3     3

I wanna create a variable test that checks whether each elements of x is in its corresponding set in tet.
I woud like to get
   x   tet  test
1: 1 1,2,3  TRUE
2: 2   4,5 FALSE
3: 3     3  TRUE

I have tried
dx[, test:= x %in% tet]

   x   tet  test
1: 1 1,2,3 FALSE
2: 2   4,5 FALSE
3: 3     3  TRUE


But of course the first row fails because it is comparing 1 against c(1,2,3) and the second row gives me a a false FALSE.
I have also tried using lapply and unlisting but to no avail.
Any ideas?

You could use mapply:
dx[,test:= mapply(`%in%`,x,tet)]
dx

#   x   tet  test
#1: 1 1,2,3  TRUE
#2: 2   4,5 FALSE
#3: 3     3  TRUE


Grouping by row and unlisting should work in this case
library(data.table)

dx[, test := x %in% unlist(tet), by=seq_len(nrow(dx))]

dx
       x    tet   test
   <num> <list> <lgcl>
1:     1  1,2,3   TRUE
2:     2    4,5  FALSE
3:     3      3   TRUE


Would grouping by row be a problem with a large dataset?

I don’t think so. It might be slower than non-rowwise operations, but I’d guess that it will only become noticeable > 1mill rows.
